# Parsing xml data from web service into database using php

Tags: php, xml

I'm currently working on a project where i have to extract some data from an online XML web service about earthquake and insert the data into a database.

My connection seems to be working since it displays "connected successfully" in my localhost web page.

The part where the code is extracting the data location, date & time, latitude longitude and magnitude does not seem to be working as it should have been displaying the success or failure message. But nothing is being displayed for this part. The data are not being in the table in phpMyAdmin.

I added an echo to see if the file is being read till the end and it showed the message "file read complete".

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYeEH.jpg)

[output image with var_dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqjjJ.jpg)

Here is my code:

```
<?php $url="https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/significant_month.quakeml";

   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   $data = curl_exec ($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
   $xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

   $db_user = 'root';
   $db_pass = '';
   $db_name = 'Earthquake';
   $db_host = 'localhost';

   $con = mysqli_connect("$db_host", "$db_user", "$db_pass", "$db_name");
if (!$con) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}else{
    echo "Connected successfully";
}

    //GETTING LOCATION OF EARTHQUAKE
    foreach ($xml -> description as $row ){
            $location = $row -> text;

            $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_earthquake (Location) VALUES (location)";

            if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "New record created successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
            }   }

        // GETTING DATE AND TIME OF EARTHQUAKE

       foreach ($xml -> time as $row){
            $datetime = $row -> value;

            $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_earthquake (DateandTime) VALUES ($datetime)";

            if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "New record created successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
            }
                }
    //GETTING LATITUDE OF EARTHQUAKE

     foreach ($xml -> latitude as $row){
            $latitude = $row -> value;

            $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_earthquake (Latitude) VALUES ($latitude)";

            if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "New record created successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
            }
                }
    //GETTING LONGITUDE OF EARTHQUAKE

     foreach ($xml -> longitude as $row){
            $longitude = $row -> value;

            $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_earthquake (Longitude) VALUES ($longitude)";

            if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "New record created successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
            }
                }
    //GETTING MAGNITUDE OF EARTHQUAKE

     foreach ($xml -> mag as $row){
            $magnitude = $row -> value;

            $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_earthquake (Magnitude) VALUES ($magnitude)";

            if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "New record created successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
            }
                } 
                var_dump($xml->description, $xml->time, $xml->latitude, $xml->longitude, $xml->mag);

                 echo"file read complete;"
   ?>
```

Comment: MySQL is your database, phpMyAdmin is just a front-end for the database.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1011527)

Comment: `VALUES (location)` should be `VALUES ('$location')` if you want to insert the value of the variable into the database.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Hello,Thank you for your help and sorry for the mistakes, I'm new to this. I just tried the ('$location') but its still not working.

Comment: Do you have any errors in your error logs?

Comment: @RoopanJaulin Please edit your question to include the output of `var_dump($xml->description, $xml->time, $xml->latitude, $xml->longitude, $xml->mag);`.

Comment: @JayBlanchard No errors in error log.

Comment: @Progman Done. Nothing is being output in this part, I neither get the success message nor the failure message. The data are not being inserted in the table either.

Comment: I find it hard to believe there are no errors.

Comment: @RoopanJaulin Where have you added the `var_dump()` calls? Please add an `echo` or `var_dump()` statement at the end of your script to verify that the script is reaching the end. It might be that your script terminated early due to an error, but your error reporting is set too low to be visible.

Comment: @Progman I just updated my code and the output image. It is reading the codes till the end.

Comment: @RoopanJaulin Please update your source code as well, including the `var_dump()` line.

Comment: @Progman I have included the var_dump line and a second output image. I never used this before since i'm new to PHP. I hope what I've inserted helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML content you are reading has two intermediate tags before you get to the relevant tags like `<description>`. When you check the XML you see the following tags:

```
<q:quakeml xmlns="http://quakeml.org/xmlns/bed/1.2" 
           xmlns:anss="http://anss.org/xmlns/event/0.1" 
           xmlns:catalog="http://anss.org/xmlns/catalog/0.1" 
           xmlns:q="http://quakeml.org/xmlns/quakeml/1.2">
    <eventParameters publicID="quakeml:earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/significant_month.quakeml">
        <event catalog:datasource="us"
               catalog:eventsource="us"
               catalog:eventid="2000i5mj"
               publicID="quakeml:earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/us2000i5mj.quakeml">
            <description>
                [...]
```

You have to read these `<eventParameters>` and `<event>` tags as well. Check the whole XML code from the source and check the structure of the XML file (which tag is contained in which other tag). You might need an XML beautifier/formatter for a better view (maybe your browser has one built in) because the XML code in the source does not have line breaks, which makes it difficult to read.

Comment: I take that into consideration. Thank You.